# Why is the auxilary verb omitted in the "how long before you get off work"?

Tags: questions

Why is the auxilary verb omitted in the following question?

> How long before you get off work?

Shouldn't it be asked with the auxilary verb? For example:

> How long before **do** you get off work?

Comment: I would interpret *How long before you get off work?* as an abbreviated form of *How long is it before you get off work?*, so the *how long* question relates to the invisible *it* rather than *[do] you*.  I can't explain the technicality of auxilary verbs well enough to make this a proper answer though.

Comment: I have never heard *"How long before **do** you get off work?"* I don't think there is a omitted "do" because it shouldn't be there in the first place. The full question is *"How long is it going to be before you get off work?"* You can also say *"How long will it be before ..."*

Comment: The auxiliary ***do*** would be included in certain relatively contrived contexts. For example, *The movie starts at 8 o'clock. How long before do we queue up to buy tickets?*, where there's an implied ***that** [time]* (i.e. - *How long before **8 o'clock...***) do we need to take our place in the queue? Another possible context might be if someone's asking you out for a drink after work, and he thinks you'll be leaving work at the same time as him (in a few minutes), but you just told him you your working day isn't "nearly over" yet. So he wants to know when you ***do*** finish (emphatic).